# how to check if the input is a number or not in C?

Tags: c, types

In the main function of C:

```
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   // do something here
}
```

In the command line, we will type any number for example `1` or `2` as input, but it will be treated as char array for the parameter of argv, but how to make sure the input is a number, in case people typed `hello` or `c`?

Comment: Use `getopt()` for arguments. http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt

Comment: Do `sscanf` and check if the return value is correct. Consult the man pages for details.

Comment: Off topic: You should use `int main() { return 0; }`.

Comment: @squiguy The `return 0;` is implicit (from C99), and actually leaving the parameter list empty is also bad.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Another way of doing it is by using isdigit function. Below is the code for it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAXINPUT 100
int main()
{
    char input[MAXINPUT] = "";
    int length,i; 

    scanf ("%s", input);
    length = strlen (input);
    for (i=0;i<length; i++)
        if (!isdigit(input[i]))
        {
            printf ("Entered input is not a number\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    printf ("Given input is a number\n");
}
```

Comment: If an input has any float or double num then its output will be wrong.

Comment: input -->"-45" in this case? what happen will this program work

Comment: Will `isdigit()` return `true` if a `float` is given?

Comment: This code could run into buffer overflow problems if some recalcitrant user (or attacker) entered more than 99 digits.  Ideally, you'd use `scanf("%99s", input)` to ensure that doesn't happen.  It would also be a good idea to test for EOF returned by `scanf()`; at the moment, the program reports that the given input is a number if you indicate EOF (or redirect the input from `/dev/null`).  You can't represent a 99-digit number in standard C types on most (I'm tempted to say "all", but that might be an exaggeration) computers.

Comment: should we need to use length-1 instead of length in for loop?

Answer (score 17):

You can use a function like `strtol()` which will convert a character array to a long.

It has a parameter which is a way to detect the first character that didn't convert properly. If this is anything other than the end of the string, then you have a problem.

See the following program for an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    long val;
    char *next;

    // Process each argument given.

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        // Get value with failure detection.

        val = strtol (argv[i], &next, 10);

        // Check for empty string and characters left after conversion.

        if ((next == argv[i]) || (*next != '\0')) {
            printf ("'%s' is not valid\n", argv[i]);
        } else {
            printf ("'%s' gives %ld\n", argv[i], val);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Running this, you can see it in operation:

```
pax> testprog hello "" 42 12.2 77x

'hello' is not valid
'' is not valid
'42' gives 42
'12.2' is not valid
'77x' is not valid
```

Comment: I do not understand, can you give a example?

Comment: let say, if people type c as input, the strtol will convert the c to 99?

Comment: @user2131316 No, it will not. Here 10 is used as a base, so it will at least stop at anything that's not 0-9 or a sign character.

Comment: @user2131316 Have you looked at the documentation for `strtol`? Are you aware of the existence of C documentation? You should have a basic familiarity with the C language *before* you ask questions about it at SO.

Comment: Example given, @user2131316.

Comment: This will parse ' ' as 0 ... to check for that, you need to check errno.

Comment: @Jim, the first check in the `if` statement takes care of that. If the string is `""`, then `next` will be the same as `argv[i]`.

Comment: Read more carefully ... I wrote ' ', not ''. It will also return 0 for, say, `"     -"`.

Comment: @Jim, if that's a single space, it'll be caught by the second part of the `if` - `next` will be left pointing to the space rather than the nul terminator. For the case of <space><minus>, that's also caught. Or, if I'm misunderstanding again, please let me know the exact character sequence in a more readable form :-)

Comment: "next will be left pointing to the space rather than the nul terminator" -- No it won't ... strtol skips whitespace.

Comment: However, I goofed ... setting errno to EINVAL is required by POSIX but not by the C standard.

Comment: @Jim, yes, it does skip white space in the conversion but, if there are no digits at all, the end pointer is set to the original argument. Hence both <space> and <space><minus> are caught okay.

Comment: "if there are no digits at all, the end pointer is set to the original argument" -- Not in a conforming implementation.

Comment: @Jim, ISO C11 7.21.1.4/7 would disagree: `If the subject sequence is empty or does not have the expected form, no conversion is performed; the value of nptr is stored in the object pointed to by endptr, provided that endptr is not a null pointer.`. `/3` spells out the requirements for the form given in this answer, digits are _necessary._

Comment: `/3`: "If the value of base is between 2 and 36 (inclusive), the
expected form of the subject sequence is a sequence of letters and digits representing an integer with the radix specified by base, optionally preceded by a plus or minus sign, but not including an integer suffix".

Comment: You're right ... I apologize for my error (and the certainty with which I stated it).

Comment: Not a problem, Jim, I had to check pretty thoroughly since your quality is usually impeccable. I'd chalk this up to one of the slightly obscure behavioural features of C.

Comment: Thank you, I try ... which makes this all the worse because of the effort I put you through.

Comment: @user2131316 "ok, but what about if we want to type value from 1 to 64?" -- The example above includes 42, which is a number between 1 and 64. It's not clear what your issue is or what you're getting at ... you need to be clearer.

Answer (score 7):

Using `scanf` is very easy, this is an example :

```c
if (scanf("%d", &val_a_tester) == 1) {
    ... // it's an integer
}
```

Comment: `sscanf` would be better but this particular solution won't catch things like `77x`.

Comment: @paxdiablo Yes it will http://ideone.com/ObOAVJ ,well i guess it depends on what you want your result to be...

Comment: @paxdiablo  Changing to `char ch; if (sscanf(argv[i], "%d%c", &val_a_tester, &ch) == 1)) {` will catch things like `77x`.

Answer (score 5):

A self-made solution:

```
bool isNumeric(const char *str) 
{
    while(*str != '\0')
    {
        if(*str < '0' || *str > '9')
            return false;
        str++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that this solution should not be used in production-code, because it has severe limitations. But I like it for understanding **C-Strings and ASCII**.

Comment: This will loop forever unless you add some str++ increment. It looks like C++ while the question asked for C.

Comment: Realized this the moment I looked at my own post. `while(*(str++) != '\0')` would also work right?

Comment: I see no severe limitations here, this code works exactly as advertised. You could add a check for an empty string but that's a trivial addition.

Comment: Well I guessed the author wants to check user input. If I enter `" 5"` into a program by accident (note the leading space) I expect it to ignore the space. Also, this function doesn't work for `"-5"` nor `"+5"` nor `"5.0"`.

Answer (score 2):

Using fairly simple code:

```
int i;
int value;
int n;
char ch;

/* Skip i==0 because that will be the program name */
for (i=1; i<argc; i++) {
    n = sscanf(argv[i], "%d%c", &value, &ch);

    if (n != 1) {
        /* sscanf didn't find a number to convert, so it wasn't a number */
    }
    else {
        /* It was */
    }
}
```

Comment: If you enter an argument like "12ab", this code will treat it as a number (11) and ignore the trailing non-digits "ab".

Comment: @Axel Kemper & OP.  Changing to `char ch; n = sscanf(argv[i], "%d%c", &value, &ch);` should fix the trailing non-digit problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this for awhile, so I thought I'd just add my two cents:

1) Create a separate function to check if an fgets input consists entirely of numbers:

```
int integerCheck(){
char myInput[4];
fgets(myInput, sizeof(myInput), stdin);
    int counter = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=0; myInput[i]!= '\0'; i++){
        if (isalpha(myInput[i]) != 0){
            counter++;
            if(counter > 0){
                printf("Input error: Please try again. \n ");
                return main();
            }
        }

    }
    return atoi(myInput); 
}
```

The above starts a loop through every unit of an fgets input until the ending NULL value. If it comes across a letter or an operator, it adds "1" to the int "counter" which is initially set to 0. Once the counter becomes greater than 0, the nested if statement instructs the loop to print an error message & then restart the program. When the loops completes, if int 'counter' is still the value of 0, it returns the initially inputted integer to be used in the main function ...

2) the main function would be:

```
int main(void){
unsigned int numberOne;
unsigned int numberTwo;
numberOne = integerCheck();
numberTwo = integerCheck();
return numberOne*numberTwo;

}
```

Assuming both integers are inputted correctly, the example provided will yield the result of int "numberOne" multiplied by int "numberTwo". The program will repeat for however long it takes to get two properly inputted integers.

Comment: wouldn't you have recursion when calling `return main();`?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sscanf(command_level[2], "%f%c", &check_f, &check_c)!=1)
{
        is_num=false;
}
else
{
        is_num=true;
}   

if(sscanf(command_level[2],"%f",&check_f) != 1) 
{
    is_num=false;
}
```

how about this?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```c
#include <string.h>

int isNumber(char *n) {

  int i = strlen(n);
  int isnum = (i>0);
  while (i-- && isnum) {
    if (!(n[i] >= '0' && n[i] <= '9')) {
      isnum = 0;
    }
  }
  return isnum;
}
```

e.g.:

```c
printf("%i\n", isNumber("12"));   // 1
printf("%i\n", isNumber("033"));  // 1
printf("%i\n", isNumber("0"));    // 1
printf("%i\n", isNumber(""));     // 0
printf("%i\n", isNumber("aaa"));  // 0
printf("%i\n", isNumber("\n"));   // 0
printf("%i\n", isNumber("a0\n")); // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The C library function int isdigit(int c) checks if the passed character is a decimal digit character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main () {
   int var1 = 'h';
   int var2 = '2';
    
   if( isdigit(var1) ) {
      printf("var1 = |%c| is a digit\n", var1 );
   } else {
      printf("var1 = |%c| is not a digit\n", var1 );
   }
   
   if( isdigit(var2) ) {
      printf("var2 = |%c| is a digit\n", var2 );
   } else {
      printf("var2 = |%c| is not a digit\n", var2 );
   }
   
   return(0);
}
```

the result is :

```
var1 = |h| is not a digit
var2 = |2| is a digit
```

Answer (score -1):

The sscanf() solution is better in terms of code lines. My answer here is a user-build function that does almost the same as sscanf(). Stores the converted number in a pointer and returns a value called "val". If val comes out as zero, then the input is in unsupported format, hence conversion failed. Hence, use the pointer value only when val is non-zero.

It works only if the input is in base-10 form.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int CONVERT_3(double* Amt){

    char number[100];

    // Input the Data
    printf("\nPlease enter the amount (integer only)...");
    fgets(number,sizeof(number),stdin);

    // Detection-Conversion begins
    int iters = strlen(number)-2;
    int val = 1;
    int pos;
    double Amount = 0;
    *Amt = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i <= iters ; i++ ){
        switch(i){
            case 0:
                if(number[i]=='+'){break;}
                if(number[i]=='-'){val = 2; break;}
                if(number[i]=='.'){val = val + 10; pos = 0; break;}
                if(number[i]=='0'){Amount = 0; break;}
                if(number[i]=='1'){Amount = 1; break;}
                if(number[i]=='2'){Amount = 2; break;}
                if(number[i]=='3'){Amount = 3; break;}
                if(number[i]=='4'){Amount = 4; break;}
                if(number[i]=='5'){Amount = 5; break;}
                if(number[i]=='6'){Amount = 6; break;}
                if(number[i]=='7'){Amount = 7; break;}
                if(number[i]=='8'){Amount = 8; break;}
                if(number[i]=='9'){Amount = 9; break;}
            default:
                switch(number[i]){
                    case '.':
                        val = val + 10;
                        pos = i;
                        break;
                    case '0':
                        Amount = (Amount)*10;
                        break;
                    case '1':
                        Amount = (Amount)*10 + 1;
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        Amount = (Amount)*10 + 2;
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        Amount = (Amount)*10 + 3;
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        Amount = (Amount)*10 + 4;
                        break;
                    case '5':
                        Amount = (Amount)*10 + 5;
                        break;
                    case '6':
                        Amount = (Amount)*10 + 6;
                        break;
                    case '7':
                        Amount = (Amount)*10 + 7;
                        break;
                    case '8':
                        Amount = (Amount)*10 + 8;
                        break;
                    case '9':
                        Amount = (Amount)*10 + 9;
                        break;
                    default:
                        val = 0;
                }
        }
        if( (!val) | (val>20) ){val = 0; break;}// val == 0
    }

    if(val==1){*Amt = Amount;}
    if(val==2){*Amt = 0 - Amount;}
    if(val==11){
        int exp = iters - pos;
        long den = 1;
        for( ; exp-- ; ){
            den = den*10;
        }
        *Amt = Amount/den;
    }
    if(val==12){
        int exp = iters - pos;
        long den = 1;
        for( ; exp-- ; ){
            den = den*10;
        }
        *Amt = 0 - (Amount/den);
    }

    return val;
}


int main(void) {
    double AM = 0;
    int c = CONVERT_3(&AM);
    printf("\n\n%d    %lf\n",c,AM);

    return(0);
}
```