# prevent reading and returning of string value

Tags: c

```
int getIndex(){
    int index = 0;
    do{
        printf("Enter your Index(0..80),-1 to STOP,-2 to RESTART,-3 to START NEW BOARD: ");
        scanf("%d", &index);
    } while (!(index >= -3 && index <=80));

    return index;

}
```

Hello, given that i have written the above method in C for a sudoku game board . what can i do to prevent the user from entering a alphabet? and keep prompting until the valid input is gotten. i have just started C .what is limiting me is the scanf flag specifier, i specified a int flag which means if a user enters a string, im screwed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check if the input is a number or not in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292545/how-to-check-if-the-input-is-a-number-or-not-in-c)

Comment: hello, i would like to prompt again if the user entered a invalid input other than the stated.

Comment: You need to check the return value of `scanf`. Read the documentation for that function.

Comment: If you are just starting with C, please heed this advice: do not ever use scanf.   scanf is almost never used in production code, and is only useful in learning the language.  And its application as a learning tool is hindered by the fact that using it will completely warp your learning of the language.  Use `fread` and parse the data using `strtol`.  This is a good learning experience.

Comment: @WilliamPursell "will completely warp your learning of the language". Um, that's an opinion. Here's another one: it is perfectly OK to use `scanf` while learning the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to check the return value of `scanf` and then clear the character from the input buffer(`stdin`) if any invalid input was entered. So change your code to the following:

```
int getIndex()
{
    int index = 0;

    while(1) //infinite loop
    {    printf("Enter your Index(0..80),-1 to STOP,-2 to RESTART,-3 to START NEW BOARD: ");
        if(scanf("%d", &index)==1) //scanf is successful scanning a number(input is a number)
        {
          if(index >= -3 && index <= 80) // if input is in range
          break; //break out of while loop
          printf("Number must be in range of -3 to 80\n"); //input is a number,but not in range
        }
        else  //input is not a number
        {
        scanf("%*s"); //Clear invalid input
        //printf("Invalid input\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n"); //printf also works but errors are meant to be in the stderr
        }

    }

    return index;
}
```

Comment: Error belong on stderr.  `fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");`

Comment: what does the flag %*s mean?

Comment: @sutoL ,`%*s` tells `scanf` to scan a string(`%s`) and then discard it

Comment: @WilliamPursell , It doesn't make a difference as there is no input redirection here. However,I've added your suggestion in the code

Comment: Note that if an input error occurs or the user signals the end of input (`Ctrl`+`D` on UNIX, `Ctrl`+`Z` on DOS), then _both_ `scanf()` calls will return `0` and you will **never** break out of the infinite loop.

Comment: @NisseEngström , I've tried signalling `EOF` using CTRL+Z(DOS),but it does not result in an infinte loop.

Comment: It does for me, using a Bash shell running under DOS. It has to be entered as the first character of the line though.

Comment: @NisseEngström ,I tried different combinations.All worked as expected and there was no infinite loop.When I press `CTRL+Z` and then enter for the 3rd time,"Invalid input" comes out but either way,there wasn't any problem

Comment: That's because some (most, I think) terminals don't close the stream on `EOF`, so you have the chance to further input something. Redirecting an empty file to `stdin`, for example, leads to an infinite loop (and apparently the terminal Nisse describes, exhibits the problem without redirection). Either way, I'd say, the code loic is flawed if it depends on receiving further input after an `EOF`.

Comment: @mafso , I see.So how can I improve the logic in the code? Do I have to assign the return value of `scanf` to another variable and test for `EOF`?

Comment: That's a way, yes. (That still has a cosmetic flaw; If the user enters `EOF` not at the beginning of a line, she's asked for further input, but then the loop exits immediately. But at least, it exits.)