# How to check if it is a number or not in C

Tags: c, validation, input

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    float a;
    float b;
    float gr;

    gr = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2;
    gr = floorf(gr*1000 + 0.5) / 1000;  
    printf("Enter two numbers: ");
    scanf("%f %f", &a, &b);


    if(isalpha(a) || isalpha(b))
    {
        printf("\nInvalid input.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    float result = a/b;

    if(floorf(result*1000+0.5)/1000 != gr)
    {
        float temp;
        temp = a;
        a= b;
        b = temp;
        result = a/b;
    }

    result = floorf(result*1000+0.5)/1000;

    if(result == gr)
    {
        printf("\nGolden ratio!\n");
    } else if(result != gr) {
        printf("\nMaybe next time.\n");
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Everything works fine except for the "if(isalpha(a) || isalpha(b))" part..
I want to make the program to check whether the user input is a number or not
but when I run it and input a and b, it prints out "Maybe next time",
not "Invalid input"...
Any help would be thankful!!

Comment: A good start will be to see what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) *returns*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to check if the input is a number or not in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292545/how-to-check-if-the-input-is-a-number-or-not-in-c)

Comment: I still dont get how to resolve the problem... can you please give me an idea?

Comment: What do you think `isalpha` with a float parameter is doing?

Comment: If [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) doesn't return `2`, then it means it failed to read two floating point numbers. You *did* read the linked reference?

Comment: does isalpha only get digit number which is 0~9 not a floating number?

Comment: @유승기 Read the [documentation of isalpha](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you type 2 letters, instead of numbers:

```
Enter two numbers: x y
```

Because you use `%f`, `scanf` expects digits. But since first letter is `x`, it will stop immediately. Both `a` and `b` are left untouched. This means 2 things:

- Since `a` and `b` are uninitialized, comparing their values makes no sense.
- Using `isalpha` on `a` and `b` makes no sense at all because the function expects *a character*, not *float*.

Luckily, `scanf` returns number of successful conversions. So change your test to

```
printf("Enter two numbers: ");    
if(scanf("%f %f", &a, &b) != 2) // 2 conversions expected
{
    printf("\nInvalid input.\n")
```