# Wanted to check if the value entered is a number or else. "isdigit() is not working here as expected

Tags: c

I am stuck with a problem here in C. I am posting the question and the code I have written below. Here I have to enter 10 numbers in an array and then I need to check how many times a number appeared. But to verify that I have entered a number and not anything else, I have used "isdigit()" function. But this is of no use. Can anyone help me to solve it.

**/*
    (a)  Ten numbers are entered from the keyboard into an array.  The  number  to  be  searched  is  entered  through  the 
    keyboard by the user. Write a program to find if the number to be searched is present in the array and if it is present, display 
    the number of times it appears in the array. 
    */**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

main()
{
    int num[10];
    int i, j, cnt=0;
    char rept;

    printf("Enter 10 numbers: \n\n");

    for(i=0; i<=9; i++)
    {
        printf("Number %d =  ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);

            fflush(stdin);

        if ( !isdigit(num[i]) )
            {
                printf("OK\n");
            }
        else
            {
                printf("Invalid number. Enter again.\n");
                i=i-1;
            }
    }


    do
    {

    printf("\nEnter the number to be searched in array:  ");
    scanf(" %d", &j);

    for (i=0 ; i<=24; i++)
    {
        if(num[i]==j)
            cnt++;

    }

        if(cnt>0)       
         printf("\nNumber %d is present at %d places", j, cnt);
         else
            printf("\nNumber not present.");

            printf("\n\nDo you want to search another number. Press Y to repeat. Any other key to exit");
            fflush(stdin);
             scanf("%c", &rept);


    }while (rept=='y'||rept=='Y');

    getch();

}
```

Comment: Who or what text suggested using `fflush(stdin);`?

Comment: Some [ideas are here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17292545/694576).

Comment: If I dont use fflush(stdin); the program ends abruptly. I used so as to clear any buffer input in the memory present.

Comment: Did you read the documentation to `scanf()`? Especially the part discussing its return value?

Comment: Also please bear in mind that `main()` went out of fashion some 20 years ago, and was made actually illegal in 2011. Use `int main(void)`.

Comment: @Coolbuddy [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011017/wanted-to-check-if-the-value-entered-is-a-number-or-else-isdigit-is-not-work#comment82990731_48011017) did not answer the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011017/wanted-to-check-if-the-value-entered-is-a-number-or-else-isdigit-is-not-work#comment82990521_48011017).  But your call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't do that. `isdigit()` is supposed to work with characters and you passed a multigit integer variable.

What you can do is simply like this

```
if( scanf("%d",&a[i])== 1){
  // you can be sure number is entered
}
```

And `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior.

So the use of `scanf` will be more prominent if you would do this

```
int clearstdin(){
  int c;
  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
  return (c == EOF);
}
```

In `main()`

```
int earlyend = 0;
for(size_t i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
...
... 
    int ret = scanf("%d",&a[i]); 
    while( ret == 0){
         if( clearstdin() ){ /* EOF found */earlyend = 1; break; }
         fprintf(stderr,"%s\n","Entered something wrong");
         ret = scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    if( earlyend ){ /*EOF found*/ }
    if( ret == EOF) { /* Error occured */}
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%d` conversion specifier will cause `scanf` to skip over any leading whitespace, then read a sequence of decimal digits, stopping at the first non-digit character.  If there are no digit characters in the input (for example, you enter something like `”abc”`), then nothing is read from the input stream, `a[i]` is not updated, and `scanf` will return 0 to indicate a *matching failure*.

So, you can do a test like

```
if ( scanf( “%d”, &a[i] ) == 1 )
{
  // user entered valid input
}
```

But...

This doesn’t fully protect you from bad input.  Suppose you enter something like `”123abc”` - `scanf` will read, convert, and assign `123` and return a 1 indicating success, leaving `”abc”` in the input stream to potentially foul up the next read.

Ideally, you’d like to reject the whole thing outright.  Personally, I do this as follows:

```
char inbuf[SOME_SIZE];  // buffer to store input

if ( fgets( inbuf, sizeof inbuf, stdin ) ) // read input as text
{
  char *chk;                                  // use strtol to convert text to integer
  int temp = (int) strtol( inbuf, &chk, 10 ); // first non-digit character written to chk
  if ( isspace( *chk ) || *chk == 0 )         // if chk is whitespace or 0, input is valid
  {
    a[i] = temp;
  } 
  else
  {
    // bad input
  }
}
```

This still isn’t a 100% solution - it doesn’t make sure the user didn’t enter more characters than the buffer can hold, but it’s a step in the right direction.

Input validation in C is, frankly, a pain in the ass.