# How can you recognize with scanf in C that the input is not a number?

Tags: c

How could I generate an error message when e.g. 'a' is the input value?

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main ( void )
{
    int a; 
    scanf ("%d" , & a) ;
    
    // if a is not a number, then generate error
    
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Don't use scanf, use fgets + strtol

Comment: It has to be scanf...

Comment: Do you want to generate an error when `a` is not an **integer**?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: Check the return value. `scanf` returns the number of items scanned, or EOF on end of file or other error.  So something like, `if (scanf ("%d", &a) == EOF) { ... handle error ...}`.

Comment: Check this link, let me know if this helps you,
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/isalpha-isdigit-functions-c-example/#:~:text=Similarly%2C%20isdigit(c)%20is,9'%20and%20zero%20for%20others.&text=Cstrings%20are%20an%20array%20of,(char)%20in%20their%20behaviour.

Comment: also check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292545/how-to-check-if-the-input-is-a-number-or-not-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to make sure that `scanf` actually correctly recognized an integer, so *check the return value*. The `scanf` family of functions returns an integer representing the number of correctly parsed elements, so if you do `scanf("%d", ...)` you should expect a return value of `1` in case of a valid integer:

```c
int a;

if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1) {
    // the value read was not an integer, the end of file was reached, or some other error occurred
} else {
    // good
}
```

This is all you can do with `scanf`, ***however*** note that this is sadly not enough to ensure that the scanned value is indeed the actual value entered by the user, and that it has not overflowed.

The only sane way in which you can do this in C is through first getting the input as a string, and then parsing it using [`strtol`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3p.html) or similar functions, which are able to correctly report parsing and overflow errors.

Comment: Be aware, `scanf( "%d", &a)` will accept an input like `"12c"` - it will successfully convert and assign `12` to `a` and leave `'c'` in the input stream to foul up the next read.  You need to check both the return value of `scanf` *and* you need to check the first character that was *not* converted - if it isn't whitespace, then you don't have a valid integer input.