# Checking if user-provided value is integer and if not asking for a correct value

Tags: c, integer

I am looking for some help with scanned user-provided values. In my code below I want to check if every entered value is integer (ca, ta, dd, gs), and if not - loop a message about it to the point where it will be. I saw few old questions about it, but I couldn't get it to work anyways. I am fairly new to programming, so I don't know much. I appreciate every answer.

```
int ca; // Current altitude
int ta; // Target altitude
int dd; // Distance for descent/climb
int gs; // Ground speed`

char cont; // variable to continue or close program

do
{
    printf("Type your current altitude: ");
    scanf("%i", &ca);

    printf("\nType your target altitude: ");
    scanf("%i", &ta);

    while(ca == ta) // If user entered same target altitude as current one, message will prompt him to type it again
    {
        printf("Target altitude needs to be different than your current one! Type it again: ");
        scanf("%i", &ta);
    }

    printf("\nType distance for descent/climb: ");
    scanf("%i", &dd);

    printf("\nType your ground speed: ");
    scanf("%i", &gs);

    int ad = ta - ca; // Calculates altitude difference - how much feet aircraft needs to descent or climb

    float time = dd*1.0 / gs*1.0; // v = s / t  =>  t = s / v  - Calculates how much time aircraft has to descent or climb (time in hours) | variables are multiplied by 1.0 to receive float in result

    int fpm = ad / (time*60); // Calculates FPM needed to descent in that time | time is multiplied by 60 in order to receive time in minutes

    if(fpm > 0)
    {
       printf("\nAircraft needs to climb at rate of %i FPM (doesn't include capturing altitude)\n", fpm);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nAircraft needs to descent at rate of %i FPM (doesn't include capturing altitude)\n", fpm);
    }

    printf("\nDo you want to run a program again? (y/n) ");
    scanf(" %c", &cont);

    while(cont != 'y' && cont != 'Y' && cont != 'n' && cont != 'N') // If user typed different character than y or n, message will prompt him to type it again
    {
        printf("\nType n or y: ");
        scanf(" %c", &cont);
    }

    printf("\n");

}
while(cont == 'Y' || cont == 'y');

return 0;
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292545/how-to-check-if-the-input-is-a-number-or-not-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making sure that user's input is really an integer is quite tricky in C, and `scanf()` isn't gonna help you much (even if used correctly, it still won't warn you about integer overflows, for instance).

One alternative is to read a line using `fgets()` and then parse it with `atoi()`, but `fgets()` will give you headaches when input line is longer than maximum length. Also, `atoi()` won't let you know if the number is valid or not (technically it does catch some errors, but you cannot distinguish them from `0`), so it may be replaced with `strtol()`.

Therefore, this is a possible approach:

```c
#include <stdio.h> // printf(), fflush(), fgetc(), EOF
#include <errno.h> // errno
#include <stdlib.h> // EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE, strtol()

#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 100 // this is the maximum size that a user's input line can be

// FUNCTION: int get_line_and_discard(char[], int);
// this function will help us read a line from `stdin`, and if user's line is longer than `str_size - 1`, the function will discard all user input until '\n'
// this will help us avoid some bugs around the use of `fgets()`
// RETURN VALUE: -1 in case of EOF or other fatal errors, 0 in case user's line is too long or empty, otherwise the line's length
// NOTE: `str` will not contain the newline and will always be NUL-terminated in case return value is >= 0
int get_line_and_discard(char str[], int str_size) {
  if (str_size < 1) {
    return -1;
  }

  int count = 0;

  while (1) {
    int c = fgetc(stdin);

    if (c == EOF) {
      return -1;
    }

    if (c == '\n') {
      str[count] = '\0';
      return count;
    }

    if (count >= str_size - 1) {
      while (1) {
        int temp = fgetc(stdin);
        if (temp == '\n' || temp == EOF) {
          break;
        }
      }
      str[0] = '\0';
      return 0;
    }

    str[count] = (char) c;

    count += 1;
  }
}

// FUNCTION: int get_number_from_user(const char*, long*);
// this function will print `ask_str` and will read a `long` integer from user
// RETURN VALUE: -1 in case of fatal errors (e.g.: EOF), 0 in case number is not valid, 1 in case of success
int get_number_from_user(const char *ask_str, long* result) {
  // print the `ask_str`
  printf("%s", ask_str);
  fflush(stdout);

  char str[MAX_LINE_SIZE];

  // read a line from `stdin`
  int slen = get_line_and_discard(str, MAX_LINE_SIZE);

  // in case of EOF or fatal errors
  if (slen < 0) {
    return -1;
  }

  // in case line is empty
  if (slen < 1) {
    return 0;
  }

  // now let's use `strtol()` to parse the number
  char *str_end;
  errno = 0;
  *result = strtol(str, &str_end, 10);

  // check that `strtol()` has not failed
  if (errno != 0 || str_end != &str[slen] || str == str_end) {
    return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

And this is how you use it:

```c
int main(void) {
  long res;

  // ask the user to input a number until the number is valid
  while (1) {
    int r = get_number_from_user("Insert number: ", &res);

    if (r < 0) {
      printf("ERROR: fatal error\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (r == 0) {
      printf("ERROR: invalid number, please retry.\n");
      continue;
    }

    break;
  }

  printf("You have input: %ld\n", res);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Minor error:  Code does not fail input of only `"\n"`.  Suggets  `errno != 0 || str_end != &str[slen]` --> `str == str_end || errno || *str_end`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica What do you mean? `get_number_from_user()` fails as expected for empty lines (it returns `0`). `str` will never contain the trailing `'\n'` (contrary to when you use `fgets()`), so `str_end` must point to the NUL character `str[slen]`.

Comment: Yes, `get_number_from_user()` fails as expected for a line of only `"\n"`.  "str will never contain the trailing '\n'", is true, yet my "input of only "\n"" refered to input, not `str`.  Since `str[slen]` is, by construction a _null character_, `str_end != &str[slen]` is replaceable with `*str_end`.  `str == str_end` remains a better test for _no conversion_ as `len` is the offset of the appended null character and not certainly the first null character in `str[]` should one have been read.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Oh yea, `str_end != &str[slen]` can be replaced with `*str_end`. About the test `str == str_end`, I'm not sure why you believe it's necessary: if conversion fails, `errno` will be different from `0`, and if `errno == 0`, then `str` cannot be `str_end`. Am I missing something?

Comment: "if conversion fails, errno will be different from 0" is not specified by C to be true.  "If the subject sequence is empty or does not have the expected form, no conversion is performed; the value of nptr is stored in the object pointed to by endptr, provided that endptr is not a null pointer." - `errno` is not specifed to change in this case.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You're right about `errno`, it appears to be set just in case of range errors. About the `str == str_end` check, I've added it to my answer as defensive programming best practice, but I still don't believe it's necessary: if `str == str_end` is true, then `str_end != &str[slen]` will also be true, so it's a redundant check (because `slen` is not smaller than `1` when `strtol()` is called).

Answer (score 1):

> I want to check if every entered value is integer

Instead of `printf(...); scanf("%i", ...);`, form a helper function.

```
int get_int(const char *prompt) {
  int value = 0;
  for (;;) {
    fputs(prompt, stdout);
    int count = scanf("%i", &value);
    if (count == 1) {
      return value;
    } 
    if (count == EOF) { // No more input
      return 0; // or some other default value.
    } 
    // No numeric input, consume rest of the line
    puts("value is not integer");
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
      ;
    }
  }
}


....
// printf("Type your current altitude: ");
// scanf("%i", &ca);
ca = get_int("Type your current altitude: ");

// printf("\nType your target altitude: ");
// scanf("%i", &ta);
ta = get_int("Type your target altitude: ");
```

More elaborate input error checking possible with `fgets(), strtol()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily if you declare your variables as a string, then later if it is correct, you can change it to an integer.

```
char user_input[100];
scanf("%s", &user_input);
while (!is_int(user_input))
{
    scanf("%s", &user_input);
}
int number = atoi(user_input);
```

**The function:**

```
int is_int(char* user_input)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (user_input[i])
    {
        int num = user_input[i];
        if (!(num >= '0' && num <= '9'))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Just a note in your `is_int()` function: the first char of `user_input` (i.e.: when `i == 0`) can also be `+` or `-`, not only a digit.

Comment: It will work well too, '+' and '-' as ASCII values too.

Comment: Yea, but you don't check for them. Your `if` should be `if (!(num >= '0' && num <= '9') && (i != 0 || (num != '+' && num != '-'))) { ... }`.