# Debug Assertion Failed in Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm trying to run the executable of this code but I'm having problems when creating it, specifically with the debug assertion error in VS. I have a screenshot of the error here and I see it mentions something about "istype.cpp" but it should be a .c program (it's named Project2.c and I've saved several times). I've also included a screenshot of the exception that's thrown in the debug screen. I've tried running in both x86 and x64 so I'm really not sure what it could be.
[error screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RlWU.png)
[debug breakpoint here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJn3O.png)

(just went through it again and fixed the if block but still not luck)
the for loop in incomplete right now because I'm trying to work step by step to get everything working properly from the start, eventually it's going to be used to sort through a file finding digits and increasing the numValues by 1 each time one is found.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void heapify(int arr[], int n, int i)
{
    int largest = i;
    int left = 2 * i + 1;
    int right = 2 * i + 2;
    
    if (left < n && arr[left] > arr[largest])
    {
        largest = left;
    }
    
    if (right < n && arr[right] > arr[largest])
    {
        largest = right;
    }
    
    if (largest != i)
    {
        swap(&arr[i], &arr[largest]);
        heapify(arr, n, largest);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    
    int numValues = 0;
    int n = sizeof(argv) / sizeof(argv[0]);
    
    for (int i = 0; argv[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(argv[i]) != 0)
            ;
        numValues++;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int n = sizeof(argv) / sizeof(argv[0]);` That's what `argc` is for.

Comment: `if (isdigit(argv[i]) != 0);` Don't think you want that `;`

Comment: `isdigit(argv[i])` works on `char` not `char *`.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; argv[i] != '\0'; i++)` - what is that loop supposed to do exactly?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: [how to check if the input is a number or not in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17292578)

Comment: You'll need to justify that C++ tag. The code looks to be 100% C. In C++ it would still work, but it would look a little different. `std::swap`, for example.

Comment: Side note: It looks like my code formatter made one of the bugs pointed out by Johnny Mopp much more obvious. take a look at that `;` it placed on its own indented line, making the `if` statement completely useless.

Comment: I strongly suspect this **isn't C++**, as C++ [won't allow](https://godbolt.org/z/WMPM668fY) your attempt to compare a pointer with `'\0'` or pass a pointer to `isdigit`.  Removing the tag-spam.

Comment: I stand corrected on my claim that it would still work.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely wrong

```
for (int i = 0; argv[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (isdigit(argv[i]) != 0)
        ;
    numValues++;
}
```

A big give away is the complaint you are receiving about isdigit call

> 1>C:\work\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp(45,28): warning C4047: 'function': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'char *'

It expects an int and you are passing a char*

Next that ; is for sure wrong , the if statement does nothing

Finally you are looping through argv expecting to find one = '0' to tell you to stop. There isnt one. Thats what argc is for. This, by the way, is why the abort happened , you ran off the end of the command line trying to read random stuff

Its not clear what you are trying to do, are you trying to see if an array of numbers is being passed in the command line?, or are you trying to inspect a single argument?. It feels like the former. This will do it

```
 for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){ // start at 1 [0] is special
     char *arg = argv[i];
     int isAllDigits = 1;
     for(int j=0; j < strlen(arg); j++){
        if(!isdigit(arg[j])){
            isAllDigits = 0;
            break;
     }
     if(isAllDigits)
        numvalues++;
   }
```

this counts how many numeric values there are on the command line

for example I tested with

```
 42 1 5 tree 6
```

and got the answer 4